# Totally geodesic submanifolds of SO(3)

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, 3-manifolds

Consider the special orthogonal group $SO(3)$ with its bi-invariant metric (or equivalently, with the metric induced by its standard embedding to the space of $3\times 3$ real matrices).
Obviously, $SO(2)$ forms a totally-geodesic submanifold of it.

*Are there any other non-trivial closed totally-geodesic submanifolds of $SO(3)$ that are not isometric to $SO(2)$? Is there a classification of them?*

Comment: $SO(3)$ is a round 3-sphere (modulo involution). So it has totally geodesic hypersurfaces, namely 2-spheres (modulo involution), that is, copies of $P^2$. For instance, one can view $SO(3)$ as the unit sphere in the quaternions $a+bi+cj+dk$, modulo $s\mapsto -s$. Taking $d=0$ yields a hypersurface of this kind.